# How to set simTime() to ZERO in the middle of simulation in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

I need a code in OMNeT++ to set the simulation time `simTime()` to zero.
Is there any way to do that?
I find out that it has ZERO flag but actually it does not help me,
and also `SimTime::setScaleExp()` can't help me neither .

```
SimTime::setScaleExp(): Attempt to change the scale exponent after initialization.
```

So is it possible to change simulation time after awhile ?

Comment: SimTime::ZERO is not worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

I'm absolutely sure, you don't need to set the simulation time to zero. Just like you cannot time travel in real world to the past, you cannot reset the simulation time in OMNET to 0. That would violate causality... In some way you misunderstand, how the simulation is supposed to work.

Comment: actually my simtime going to over out of range , that's why i wanna reset it and continue my simulation

Comment: at event #576847, t=58589.398513325374: Cannot convert inf to simtime_t: out of range (-9223372.036854775807,9223372.036854775807), allowed by scale exponent -12.

Comment: So you really don't want to set it to zero, but want to avoid rather an error. This is definitely an error in your model. At t=58589s (10.6 hours) in simulation time, you are trying to schedule an event into the far future which is further that 9223372s (106days) in the future, while the simulation is configured to have a 1 picosecond accuracy. You should check the model, and see why it is scheduling events into the future. Usually this comes down to an incorrectly configured inter arrival time or something similar.