# simulate for 1 month in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I want to simulate for 100 minutes in omnet++ but every time I use the big value for the sim_time it gives an error,

```
A runtime error occurred,
cannot convert 3.6e +007 out of range
```

how should I simulate for a long time?

Comment: This may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58761336/how-to-set-simtime-to-zero-in-the-middle-of-simulation-in-omnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue by adding the scale of simulation time to some less value which is by default -12 so I just decrease the value to avoid the event which is scheduled in the future.

```
simtime-scale=-9 #or less
```

in the omnet.ini file.